# How to pick one number of an Integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I pick one of the digits from an Integer like: 97723
and choose (for example) the number 2 from that number and check if its an odd or an even number?

Also, can I print only the odd numbers from an Integer directly? (Is there any default function for that already?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: str(97723)[3] % 2 == 0 # will probably do it?

Comment: honestly i didn't find anything to try yet, I didn't find any function that reads an integer digit to digit

Comment: Sam Redway, str(97723)[3] it's what I was looking for, Thanks :)

Comment: str(97723)[3] is a string, so str(97723)[3] % 2 will raise an exception.

Comment: true, i can always convert the string to a digit again after selecting it tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 is the 4th digit.

You can get the digits of a number using this construct.

```
digits = [int(_) for _ in str(97723)]
```

This expression will be `true` if the 4th digit is even.

```
digits[3] % 2 == 0
```

Comment: This won't generalize. I think the OP is looking for a method to pick an arbitrary digit out of a number.

Comment: My objective was to offer a simple answer to a simple question. What sort of generalisation would you like?

Answer (score 1):

```
# choose a digit (by index)

integer = 97723

digit_3 = str(integer)[3]

print(digit_3)

# check if even:

if int(digit_3) % 2 == 0:
    print(digit_3, "is even")


# get all odd numbers directly

odd_digits = [digit for digit in str(integer) if int(digit) % 2 == 1]

print(odd_digits)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
even = lambda integer: int("".join([num for num in str(integer) if int(num) % 2 == 0]))
```

or

```
def even(integer):
    result = ""
    integer = str(integer)
    for num in integer:
        if int(num) % 2 == 0:
            result += num
    result = int(result)
    return(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "parse" a number the easiest way to do this is to convert it to string. You can convert an int to string like this `s = string(500)`. Then use string index to get character that you want. For example if you want first character (number) then use this `string_name[0]`, for second character (number) use `string_name[1]` . To get length of your string (number) use `len(string)`. And to check if number is odd or even mod it with 2.

```
# Converting int to string
int_to_sting = str(97723)

# Getting number of characters in your string (in this case number)
n_of_numbers = len(int_to_sting)

# Example usage of string index
print("First number in your number is: ",int_to_sting[0])
print("Second number in your number is: ",int_to_sting[1])

# We need to check for every number, and since the first number is int_to_sting[0] and len(int_to_sting) returns actual length of string we need to reduce it by 1
for i in range(n_of_numbers-1):
        if int_to_sting[i]%2==0:
              print(int_to_sting[i]," is even")
        else:
              print(int_to_sting[i]," is odd")
```